# PHP | If loop with multiple conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a problem with an if loop with more than one condition inside I bring an example to understand:

for example let's say we have 3 fields in the same database table

```
one

two

three
```

each of these 3 fields has 3 states

```
empty

on hold

ready
```

I want to see a statement only when all 3 are up ready

```
    <?php if($collaboratore_abilitato['one'] === 'ready'|| $collaboratore_abilitato['two'] === 'ready' || $collaboratore_abilitato['three'] === 'ready') :?>

<!-- SHOW CODE -->

<?php else: ?>

<!-- SHOW ANTOHER CODE -->


    <?php endif; ?>
```

and

```
$collaboratore_abilitato
```

it s a paramater for a while

my problem is that when I activate the 3 parameter it shows me the contents of show code and not of show another code

I don't understand why it should show me show another code only when the 3 statements are verified in ready

Comment: `||` means if any are `ready`, you may want `&&` to check that they are all `ready`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change || to && for check that they are all `ready`

```
<?php 
      if (
           $collaboratore_abilitato['one'] === 'ready' &&
           $collaboratore_abilitato['two'] === 'ready' &&
           $collaboratore_abilitato['three'] === 'ready' 
         ): 
?>

    <!-- SHOW CODE -->

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- SHOW ANTOHER CODE -->

<?php endif; ?>
```